# Why can C++ use the uninitialized member variables (reference or pointer *NOT value copy*) to initialize the member variables of its parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management, initialization

I have two questions about initializing the member variables in C++.

1. Why does the code `explicit Apple(const char* name) :Fruits(&_name)` work when the construction function of `Fruits` is defined as `explicit Fruits(std::string* f_n) :f_name_(f_n)` (or when the pointers in these codes are replaced with reference)?
2. Whether are the member variables of the derivated class allocated memories after or before the member variables of its sub-base class?

please see the code below.

```
// Apple.h c++
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>

class Plant {
public:
    Plant() {
        std::cout << "Plant construction function called." << std::endl;
    }
    inline void show() {
        std::cout << "name：" << s_name_ << std::endl;
    }

    void Init() {
        std::cout << "Init assign value called." << std::endl;
        s_name_ = this->getName();
    }
    virtual ~Plant() {
        std::cout << "Plant deconstruction function called." << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string s_name_;

protected:
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
};

class Fruits: public Plant{
public:
    explicit Fruits(std::string* f_n) :f_name_(f_n) {
        std::cout << "Fruits construction function called."<< std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Fruits() {
        std::cout << "Fruits deconstruction function called." << std::endl;
    }
protected:
    std::string getName() override {
        std::cout << "getName() function called." << std::endl; 
        return *f_name_;
    }
private:
    std::string* f_name_;
};

class Apple:public Fruits {
private:
    std::string _name;
public:
    explicit Apple(const char* name) :Fruits(&_name) {
        _name = name;
        std::cout << "Apple constuction function called."<< std::endl;
        Plant::Init();
    }

    ~Apple() {
        std::cout << "Apple deconstruction function called." << std::endl;
    }
};

// main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "Apple.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    {
        cout << "test1:" << endl;
        Apple t1("Apple1");
        t1.show();
    }
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all why this danger game with pointer, just keep it by value.

Comment: Regarding your first question: `name` is not the same as `_name`.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean in the first question, please try to rephrase it.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd question, the base class is always created first.  But then your text book already covered that.

Comment: @UKMonkey confusing here is term "created". They all created at once, they initialized from base to derived.

Comment: @Slava well, if you're going to correct me you can go a step further and say that they're initialised in order they're listed in the class... :P  I was trying to point out however this is covered in every single introduction level c++ book.

Comment: @UKMonkey problem is this simplified explanation does not allow to understand why it is possible to create a pointer to derived class member (it is not "created" yet so how it is possible to have a pointer to something wasn't created yet?) and what consequences that have.

Comment: @Slava Thank you for your answer. There I want to ask why C++ allowes the uninitilized `_name` (@G.M. thanks) to construct the sub-object of `Fruits` in `Apple` when using pointer or reference. `_name` is my question. I know it can be done by a safe value copy. Now I know the reason from your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the code explicit Apple(const char* name) :Fruits(&_name) work when the construction function of Fruits is defined as explicit Fruits(std::string* f_n) :f_name_(f_n) (or when the pointers in these codes are replaced with reference)?

You pass address of the member variable `_name` which is of type `std::string` so it compiles fine and `explicit` is unrelated to this. Note you play very dangerous game here, if you try to dereference that pointer inside constructor of `Fruits` you will get UB.

> Whether are the member variables of the derivated class allocated memories after or before the member variables of its sub-base class?

Your question shows that you do not understand how it works. Derived class is an object which resides on `sizeof(typename)` memory which include base object and all member variables added by derived if any. When memory allocated for it,  it is allocated for whole object at once, not by parts of it. Different issue is order of initialization - though memory is allocated objects are initialized from base to derived, so if you try to access objects of derived class in base class constructor you get UB as you would try to access uninitialized object.

Comment: Thank you. Of course, the `_name` has not been initilized when calling the `Fruits` construction function.  `Fruits(&_name)` passes the address of the memory for  `_name`. Even though `_name` has not been initilized, it's memory has been allocated at the same time with `f_name_` and `s_name_`. So a pointer to `_name` is ok. And when create an Apple object the member variables have been defined, so adding a reference to some variable is ok. Just watch out! DON NOT use a variable before initilzing it. So `explicit Fruits(std::string f_n) :f_name_(f_n)` is wrong.That's what i got from the ans.

Answer (score 0):

Cause it's just adding a constructor with a different signature to Apple. This has nothing to do with Fruit.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Why does the code explicit Apple(const char* name) :Fruits(&_name) work when the construction function of Fruits is defined as explicit
>   Fruits(std::string* f_n) :f_name_(f_n) (or when the pointers in these
>   codes are replaced with reference)?

your `explicit Fruits(std::string* f_n)` wants pointer on std::string `_name` is a member of Apple of type std::string, so taking an address of `_name` will cast to needed std::string*.

> 2. Whether are the member variables of the derivated class allocated memories after or before the member variables of its sub-base class?

Firstly initializes parent class, after that derived class. so in your case passing `Fruits(&_name)` here:

```
explicit Apple(const char* name) :Fruits(&_name) {
        _name = name;
```

means _name is uninitialized at this moment, it will be initialized after Fruits constructor will be finished

Comment: "so taking a reference from it" & in this context is not related to references, this is operator "address of"